# Configure OpenCV 2.2 with Borland on C::B

Tags: c++, opencv, c++builder

Hii all,,

I have some project that requires me to do Image processing, I used to work with MATLAB but it is just too slooowww, Searching for an alternative lands me up to OpenCV. I am used to C::B with Borland Compiler 5.5, and to my luck, borland is not supported by default, I have googled it but ain't no luck.

Please, it would be of great help, if anyone can help me out to configure it all..

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a compiler wrapper to convert from g++ compiler options to Borland C. Then use the configure script to discover the settings that are needed for your compilation environment.

You can take the compiler wrapper for msvc and modify it for Borland. It can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/wrapmsvc/).

Next you should install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) so that the typical Unix tools such as sh are available on your system.

Run the OpenCV configure script as mentioned in INSTALL. You may have to fix things as you go along. Using the config.log to see failure messages, if any.